# LoggerDynamicMBean log4j 1.x to log42

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, jmx, mbeanexporter

So I was trying to migrate our legacy application java log4j 1.x to log4j2

I saw a great article with regards to migrating this log4j using the bridge API. However, there's one thing that I am stuck with.

Here is the culprit

```
   ObjectName addLoggerMBean(MBeanServer server, Logger logger)
{
    String name = logger.getName();
    ObjectName objectName = null;
    
    try
    {
        LoggerDynamicMBean loggerMBean = new LoggerDynamicMBean(logger);
        objectName = new ObjectName("log4j.category", "logger", name);

        if (!server.isRegistered(objectName))
        {
            server.registerMBean(loggerMBean, objectName);
           
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // log.error("Could not add loggerMBean for ["+name+"].", e);
    }
    
    return objectName;
}
```

So the snippet above was creating the instance of `LoggerDynamicMBean` under the library of `org.apache.log4j.jmx.LoggerDynamicMBean` and unfortunately, it seems that this is not part of the existing [log4j bridge API](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html).

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Sorry for the nub question, just new on java an this application doesn't even run locally. So think of that :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your question just exports some logger data though JMX for a monitoring tool. Performing a migration is the best time to reevaluate the utility of code like this.

If you don't use JMX monitoring tools just drop the code.

If you **do** use JMX monitoring tools, the code is also useless, since Log4j 2.x exports data through JMX by default (cf. [`LoggerConfigAdminMBean`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/javadoc/log4j-core/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/jmx/LoggerConfigAdminMBean.html)). You'll need however to adapt the monitoring tool for a different set of data.

Comment: I read about this in log4j 2.x docx, but I don't have enough knowledge about this. Your comment is pretty helpful for me to understand what needs to be done. Thank you!